# Crystal reports 5.2 client?

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

I've received the source code of an old vb6.0 app that uses Crystal Reports.

The original project file shows:

```
Object={00025600-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}#5.2#0; Crystl32.OCX
```

In my old visual basic 6.0 installation CDs I only have crystal reports version 4.6.

When I try to open one of the rpt files from the source code using the Crystal Report Pro (version 4.6) it raises a cannot open rpt error. I suspect the rpt were saved using a "Crystal Report Pro version 5.2" or something similar.

Do you know if this version (5.2) exists? 
And how can I get a working copy of this version of crystal reports pro for editing the rpts?

Upgrade to a newer crystal version is an option as long as it works in visual basic 6.0 the same way, ie with Crystl32.ocx, same APIs, etc.....

Answer (score 0):

I had a project where I had to take some old 4.6 reports and regenerate them with version 8.  I was able to use it, but as I recall (it's been about 10 years) I had to regenerate the rpt files before they would work.  I had to do something like open them and resave them as a new file.  A little googling suggests that CR only supports forward migration of older reports (can't save in old format), so your last paragraph is probably not going to happen.

Comment: The problem I face here is I don't know exactly how the rpt's were created. The only hints are: the vb project has reference to a 5.2 Crystl32.ocx and the fact that I cannot open the rpts with the 4.6 Crystal Report Pro editor. At this point I don't know how to open the rpt. With Crystal Report Viewer I cannot open the rpt's either. It says the rpt are too old. So it should be someting in between the 4.6 and the 9.0. Not sure if the 8.5 is able to open them. I don't have a 8.5 instalation media